# HostBinding to anonymous lambda function?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm using `@HostBinding` to bind the results of a function to the host element's visible attribute:

```
@HostBinding('attr.visible')
private get visibleAttr(): any {
  return this._visible ? '' : null;
}
```

The function name seems redundant because nothing else will ever call this function. I tried to declare it like an anonymous lambda function but it didn't work:

```
@HostBinding('attr.visible') (() => {
  return this._visible ? '' : null;
})
```

Is there a way to declare this function anonymously, or at least with a lambda? Or does the Angular framework depend on it being named?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`@HostBinding`](https://angular.io/api/core/HostBinding) is a decorator and needs a valid member to decorate. *If* your 2nd code example

```
(() => {
  return this._visible ? '' : null;
})
```

on it's own was a valid member it could work *but* this is not valid typescript (or javascript) for a member declaration. As such it can't work.